# 404 Редирект в denwer .htaccess

Tags: denwer

вопрос:
Создал файил .htaccess в корне сайта. В него вписал

`ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/logika/index.php`

Но по каким-то причинам всеравно выдает страницу ошибки денвера.
Может кто сталкивался?
Перезапускал денвер, проверял файл на кодировку UTF-8 без BOM.

Не понимаю что нужно сделать чтобы перенаправлял...

Answer (score 2):

Вообщем воспользовался такой конструкцией

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

.htaccess перенаправляет на страницу index.php